# AsyncTask with Fragment in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-viewpager

I'm trying to load data from a server in Fragment using AsyncTask and ProgressDialog. 
Here is the PageAdapter code

```
public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch (i){
            case 0: return  new Fragment1();
            case 1: return new Fragment2();
            case 2: return new Fragment3();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Here is how I use the adapter

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

And the code in the fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    appContext= (SApplication) getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    mList.clear();
    this.rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_event, container, false);
    mListView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.events);
    this.asycnTask=new HttpRequestTask(getActivity());
    return rootView;
}
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        if(asycnTask.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.PENDING)) {
            this.asycnTask.execute();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that the asyncTask is executed every time I swipe to fragment 3. I only need for the AsyncTask to be executed once.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just set a flag  that blocks subsequent runs?

```
private boolean wasAlreadyRunOnce;
.
.
.

    if (isVisibleToUser && !wasAlreadyRunOnce) {
          if(asycnTask.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.PENDING)) {
                this.asycnTask.execute();
                wasAlreadyRunOnce = true;
           }
    }
```